# How to get the data from Mongodb and print it in a specific file created in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, visual-studio-code

I want to retrieve the data from Mongodb atlas and print it inside the file which has been developed in react.

I have been the code which contains console.log(result) and another function to get the data from Mongodb

```js
      users.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next){
        var resultArray=[];
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
          assert.equal(null, err);
          var cursor=db.collection('users').find();
          cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
            assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
          }, function(){
            db.close();
            res.render('Mypatient', {items: resultArray})
          })
        })
     }
```

-Above is the code to fetch the data.
-the code is working absolutely fine, giving 0 errors and it is also printing the values in console.
-How can i write the data that is been fetched now in the specified file "abcd" which has been developed using react?

```html
     <div className="appoint_class">
       <ListGroup>
       <ListGroup.Item action variant="primary" className="list_group">
       <h4 style={{ textAlign: "start" }}>Mr. Shawn Louis</h4>
       <h6 style={{ textAlign: "start" }}>Cat</h6>
       </ListGroup.Item>
       </ListGroup>
     </div>
```

-This is my html file. I have my get method in another file and the above html file is in *MyPatient.js*.
-How do I transfer the value fetched from one js file to another so that I can use it to display in the front end. And how can I run that in a for loop.

Comment: Sounds like you want to render a react component(s) with Express `res.render()` method, is that right?

Comment: yes. i have edited the post...you can check that once

Comment: First, you need to setup a view engine that is capable of rendering react components, [react-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-engine) is an example view engine that can help you do that. Afterward, passing data into the view should be as simple as passing props down into a react component.